# Read a column then write in another column from a CSV file with Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, data-science

I have a CSV file which contains 10 lines and 5 column.

For each lines, excepted first line, 
I need to read column 2 and to recognize the beginning or the end of the cell.
Depending on what the script reads on each column 2, it writes a letter in colomn 6 from the same line.

Thank a lot in advance if you can help me !

Here is my code :

```
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as u:
        read = csv.reader(u)
        for line in read:
            for row[2] in rows:
                if line.endswith('this_is_a_text'):
                    writer.writerow(row[6]+["WIN"])
```

Comment: Aha.. and is that giving any problem?

Comment: I presume rows is defined somewhere else?

Comment: it's giving :
" for row[2] in rows:
NameError: name 'rows' is not defined "

Comment: Post your input file and expected output.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: input : c773522e clinical.xml fdcfdf81d3974096e6e3d458461e3a60 55273‌​ live BCR XML 5522fcfc htseq.counts.gz 1adf2b92e54f678e99e15b74ea5ed653 24‌​5966 submitted TXT expected output : c773522e clinical.xml fdcfdf81d3974096e6e3d458461e3a60 55273‌​ live BCR XML clin_ovarian_cancer 5522fcfc htseq.counts.gz 1adf2b92e54f678e99e15b74ea5ed653 24‌​5966 submitted TXT d‌​rug_paclitaxel

Comment: Nick don't post code in comments.  Add code to your question.  And format it

Answer (score 1):

If that is your actual code, you do not have the variable "rows" available at the current scope. You have 'line'. Perhaps you mean something to the effect of

```
for row in reader
```

?? The documentation I'm reading says that a line is a row, there should be columns in your line/row.

Comment: if I replace :

for line in read:
            for row[2] in rows:


by  

for row in reader

I have this : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_ouverture_gzip.py", line 56, in <module>
    if line.endswith('this_is_a_text'):
NameError: name 'line' is not defined

Comment: That is because 'row' is line. Replace line.endswith ('this_is_a_text') with row.endswith ('this_is_a_text'). When you see NameError: name 'variablename' is not defined, it means that you have to look at your code and ask yourself whether there is a variable with the given name at the scope where the error was thrown. I'll give you a hint: there isn't. Define a variable with that name, and your code will continue working (hopefully correctly if you are calling the correct methods on said variable, et-c)